GNNs with higher order adjacency matrices
Usually, the adjacency matrix stores information about direct connections of nodes in a graph.
The information from k-th neighbours is passed-on at k-th layers of GNNs, as described in the original paper.
One could add extra information directly to the adjacency matrix (dis-honouring the name) or higher order matrices, to describe "connections" through other nodes (i.e higher order), and modulating the intensity.
Has this approach been proven successful? is there any canonical paper describing an implementation?

One can consider a Laplacian Polynomial, see this post for details..
The polynomial has the form:
$$X'_u=\sum_{d=0}^{d=i} w_i L_u^d X$$
where $X$ are the nodes' features, $L$ the Laplacian $L=D-M$, $M$ being the adjacency matrix, $D$ the degree matrix. $w_i$ are weights.
The key is the meaning of $M^i$ (you can consider it as $L$ for conceptual purposes.)
The powers of $M$ make up higher order connections, for example, take the graph:
A-B
|
C
|
D
|
E


When one takes $M^2$, second order connections appear, and so the slot for "M to D" has a non-zero number.
   A B C D E
   - - - - -
A| 0 1 1 0 0
B| 1 0 0 0 0                   
C| 1 0 0 1 0
D| 0 0 1 0 1
E| 0 0 0 1 0

where the rows and columns label for explanatory purposes; the squared of that matrix (i.e matrix multiplication with a copy of itself:
   A B C D E
   - - - - -
A| 2 0 0 1 0
B| 0 1 1 0 0                  
C| 0 1 2 0 1
D| 1 0 0 2 0
E| 0 0 1 0 1

Now $A$ has a connection to $D$, but not to $E$, and $C$ has now a connection to $E$.
So the power of $L$ will include higher orders naturally; the $i$-th power $L_i$ includes up to connection $i$.
